# Android ListView with CheckBox and a selectable item

Tags: android

I have seen plenty of samples which support a checkbox for each item in a list but this seems to be about as far as they go.  My problem is that I have two lists of items which interact.

The first list displays Method Statements - when the user select a method statement the second list displays a list of Risk Assesments for this method statement.  I have this all working with no issues.

I now need to extend this so that the user can select (via a checkbox) the Method Statements that they want to use.  What this means is that I do not want the selection of the listitem to set or clear the check box, just populate the second listbox.  I do however need the user to be able to manually check the item to include it.

Any suggestions please would be most welcome - maybe a ListView is not the correct way to do this, perhaps a dynamically created table within a scroll view?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this way.

1. Set choice mode of ListView as NONE.
2. Build a ViewGroup (Linear/Relative/Frame Layout) with TextView and CheckBox. It will
   be a cell of ListView.
3. When you bind view in the adapter, set CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener on the CheckBox. Place position of your view in the Integer and set it as a tag for your cell (remember: do it in the binding data with view).

   ```
     private static class MyOnCheckedChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChange(...) {
                 Integer position = (Integer) view.getTag();
                 //your logic with position
          }
      }
   ```

Or just set OnClickListener.

The idea is: let CheckBox be clickable and let it consume click events - then its parent will not receive this events and AdapterView.OnItemClickListener will not be fired.